# boost no se puede realizar la conversión de 'const std::string' a 'const std::basic_string

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

no entiendo por que me da este error porfa una ayuda de como seria el código

```
error C2664: 'std::basic_string<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t>,std::allocator<wchar_t>>::basic_string(std::initializer_list<_Elem>,const std::allocator<wchar_t> &)' : el argumento 1 no puede convertirse de 'const std::string' a 'const std::basic_string<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t>,std::allocator<wchar_t>> &'
```

el codigo que tengo actualmente

```
const std::wstring EL_SystemComplete(const std::wstring& Path)
{
    return boost::filesystem::system_complete(Path).string();
}
```

Comment: porque son diferentes tipos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema está claro, no se puede convertir:

```
const std::string
```

En:

```
const std::basic_string<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t>,std::allocator<wchar_t>>
```

Lo que parece no estar claro es lo que significa.

---

#### `std::string` es un alias de `std::basic_string`.

Para empezar debemos ahondar en lo que es un `std::string`, si consultamos la [documentación en cppreference](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string) vemos que existen los siguientes alias:

- `using std::string    = std::basic_string<char>`
- `using std::wstring   = std::basic_string<wchar_t>`
- `using std::u16string = std::basic_string<char16_t>`
- `using std::u32string = std::basic_string<char32_t>`

Sabiendo esto el error que te encuentras es que no se puede convertir:

```
const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>
```

En:

```
const std::basic_string<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t>,std::allocator<wchar_t>>
```

#### ¿Con qué tipos trabaja `boost::filesystem`?

La función [`boost::filesystem::system_complete`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#system_complete) recibe `const path&` y devuelve `path`. Los constructores de la clase [`boost::filesystem::path`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#path-constructors) son:

```
template <class Source>
  path(Source const& source, const codecvt_type& cvt=codecvt());
template <class InputIterator>
  path(InputIterator begin, InputIterator end, const codecvt_type& cvt=codecvt());
```

Dado que estás trabajando con el primer constructor (más sobre esto en el siguiente punto) debemos averiguar qué es el parámetro plantilla `Source`; por suerte Boost nos [indica sus especificaciones](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#Source)
 (traducción mía):

> #### Requisitos de `path`
>
> ...
>
> Se requiere que los parámetros plantilla llamados `Source` sean uno de los siguientes:
>
> - Un contenedor que contenga un tipo `char`, `wchar_t`, `char16_t` o `char32_t`.
> - Un iterador o una secuencia de bytes acabada en null. Se requiere que el tipo de los valores sea `char`, `wchar_t`, `char16_t` o `char32_t`.
> - Un arreglo-C. Se requiere que el tipo de los valores sea `char`, `wchar_t`, `char16_t` o `char32_t`.
> - Un `boost::filesystem::directory_entry.`.

#### Estás construyendo un `boost::filesystem::path` temporal.

En la llamada `boost::filesystem::system_complete(Path)` pasas un `std::wstring` a `boost::filesystem::system_complete`, dado que esa función recibe un `boost::filesystem::path` (no un `std::wstring`) lo que hará será construir un `boost::filesystem::path` temporal que será usado en la llamada; después esa función devuelve otro objeto `boost::filesystem::path` sobre el que llamas a la función `string`.

#### Tu problema está en la función [`boost::filesystem::path::string`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#path-native-format-observers).

Es una función plantilla:

```
template <class String>
String string(const codecvt_type& cvt=codecvt()) const;
```

En la documentación de Boost indica que si el tipo de cadena subyacente es diferente al del retorno, se hará una conversión utilizando el parámetro `cvt` proveído. Por cómo se comporta tu código, creo que tu retorno es de tipo `std::string` y por eso te falla.

#### Propuesta.

Prueba esto:

```
const std::wstring EL_SystemComplete(const std::wstring& Path)
{
    return boost::filesystem::system_complete(Path).string<std::wstring>();
    //          Especifica el tipo de cadena devuelta --> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
}
```

#### Otras cosas a tener en cuenta.

Es inútil cualificar los parámetros de retorno como constantes cuando los devuelves por valor.

Comment: inutil y contraproducente... esa práctica deshabilita la sintaxis move...

Comment: hi, this would be valid?  return boost::filesystem::system_complete(Path).c_str();

Comment: Por supuesto, pero en ese caso no sacarás provecho del constructor de movimiento de `std::basic_string` *indeed, but then you wouldn't be taking advantage of `std::basic_string` movement constructor. The official language of this page is Spanish*.